# createStructuredSelector and selectors with logical OR

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

we recently moved to reselect lib. so we have mixed data structure in `mapStateToProps`.

I use `createStructuredSelector` as next, and here is the problem:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  someProp: state.someProp,
  ...createStructuredSelector({
    pending: selectIsPending_1 || selectIsPending_2,
  })(state)
})
```

`selectIsPending_1` returns `true` only during initial load. Later - always `false`.

`selectIsPending_2` is never reached,
so in result I get always `false` in `pending` prop

How can I use this OR operator in this case?

as a workaround, inside `createStructuredSelector`:

```
    pending: () => selectIsPending_1(state) || selectIsPending_2(state),
```

Comment: Why do you need createStructuredSelector? Wouldn't this be enough?

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  somePropp: state.someProp,
  pending: selectIsAnyGlobalPending(state) || selectIsSearchPending(state),
})

Comment: Apart from that, is there a good reason you are using `mapStateToProps`? You should only be using that if you really need to use legacy class components - if you are not working on a pre-2019 codebase that cannot update react, please follow the recommendations and use `useSelector` instead of `connect`.

Comment: I've changed it to what you've suggested. But the question is still open, why false from first selector doesn't lead us to the second one. reselect doc says nothing about it